# Randomly placing objects on a circular path outside of the stage. [AS3]

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

I'm creating a game for a project and have stumbled across a problem. I have managed to figure out how to create tweens using Action Script 3 and make them go to a specific point on the stage, however my problem comes when resetting the object to a random point outside of the stage.

The game is a simple click to kill game, where enemies are approaching your base from all angles on the stage, and you need to click them multiple times to destroy them.

I am able to code the rest of the game, however I have no idea how to make object spawn at random point outside of the stage, and travel towards the center of the stage.

I have included a photo depicting what I am trying to accomplish.

Thanks in advance for any help!

http://postimg.org/image/ch8iakok7/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd do something like this :

```
// increase or decrease radius to your liking  
var radius:Number = 500; 

// get a random angle (in radians)
var angle:Number = 2 * Math.PI * Math.random();

var spawnX:Number = radius * Math.cos(angle);
var spawnY:Number = radius * Math.sin(angle);
```